# Ant design Select component OptGroup in options prop

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is it possible to add OptGroup to options prop in Select component from Ant Design (https://ant.design/components/select/)?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const Places = () => {
  function handleChange(value, objectValues) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(objectValues);
  }
return (
 <>
    <Select
      labelInValue
      defaultValue={{ value: 'Lucy' }}
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={[ // add OptGroup here ??
        { label: 'Jack', value: 'Jack', id: '1' },
        { label: 'Lucy', value: 'Lucy', id: '2' },
      ]}
     />
  </>
  );
  };

export default Places;
```

instead of doing it like this the traditional way, I want to add the OptGroup to the options prop.

```
<Select defaultValue="lucy" style={{ width: 200 }} onChange={handleChange}>
 <OptGroup label="Manager">
  <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
  <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
 </OptGroup>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, yes you can! Just pass in an object with `label` and `options` properties. Like this:

```js
function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
      labelInValue
      defaultValue={{ value: 'Lucy' }}
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={[
          {
            label: "Test",
            options:
            [
              { label: 'Jack', value: 'Jack', id: '1' },
              { label: 'Lucy', value: 'Lucy', id: '2' }
            ]
          }
      ]}
     />,
  mountNode,
);
```

Here's a working [pen](https://codepen.io/jaycodist/pen/mdPzpKV?editable=true&editors=001%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fant.design%2Fcomponents%2Fselect%2F)